# Convert __main__ function from Python script intended for command line into a callable function

Tags: python, function, command-line

I am working with someone's GitHub code that is designed to be called from the command line like so:

```
> python this_script.py -u <username> -p <password> -i <id_num> ...
```

This produces an output text file after parsing the inputs in such a manner within `this_script.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='get data', add_help=False, usage='this_script.py -u username -p password [options]')
    parser.add_argument('-u', metavar='<STR>', type=str, help='username')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='<STR>', type=str, help='password')
    parser.add_argument('-i', metavar='<STR>', nargs='+', type=str, help='List of IDs')
    ...
```

I want to use many of these text files within my own set of code, so it would be much more convenient for me to convert this from a command line script to a callable function, with syntax something like this:

```
def this_script(password, username, *args):
    ...
```

Is there a simple way to do this, without have to mess around too much with the inner workings of the `__main__` block as currently defined?

Comment: I don't see any function called `main` in your examples? It completely depends on the code... Usually you can just put everything into a function and be done, but this is not the case if the code relies on globals&stuff. And how to refactor that completely depends on the specific code. Your question as stated is too broad. You should provide a concrete example, your attempt and what is wrong with it.

Comment: The quick&dirty solution would be to assign to `sys.argv` and then run that code unchanged: `sys.argv = ['blah', '-u', username, '-p', password] + args`

Comment: @Bakuriu I thought I showed the __main__ code here? As far as I understand, that is the function that is called when the script is run from the command line, right?

Comment: By convention, inside `__main__` block is usually a call to a function named `main`.  Likely your wording was misleading, so have edited it to avoid the confusion. If, after the arguments are parsed, the script then calls a worker function with parsed arguments, then it's possibly you can just call that worker function directly - which is what Bakuriu was getting at. Regardless, the author of the script has put the argument parsing in the wrong place.

Comment: @wim Unfortunately there is not any worker function in this case. It leads into `args = parser.parse_args()` and then `args.u`, `args.p`, etc. are used throughout the function. Would it then be necessary for me to design my own function to get all these inputs? I want to leave as much code as I can untouched.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def do_stuff(args):
    print(args.u)
    print(args.p)


def main(args_list=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='get data', add_help=False, usage='this_script.py -u username -p password [options]')
    parser.add_argument('-u', metavar='<STR>', type=str, help='username')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='<STR>', type=str, help='password')
    parser.add_argument('-i', metavar='<STR>', nargs='+', type=str, help='List of IDs')
    ...

    if args_list:
        args= parser.parse_args(args_list)
    else:
        args = parser.parse_args()

    do_stuff(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

By adding the following line into your package `__init__.py`

```
from .__main__ import main
```

You can call the script as a function from command line, or from another script as long as you import your package, such as

```
import <package name> as pkg
pkg.main(['-u', 'my_username', '-p', 'my_password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simple way is to use stdlib [`runpy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html).

```
import runpy

runpy.run_module(mod_name, init_globals=None, run_name=None, alter_sys=False)
```

And, please make a mental note never to write your own scripts like that.  There should only ever be a single line under the conditional, and it should be a call to a function with no arguments, like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anything more is too much.

Comment: So I've moved all the code from under `if __name__ == "__main__":` to its own method `main()`, but now I'm not sure how I can pass it any inputs, given that it has no arguments. What would be the standard procedure for this?

Comment: Standard procedure is for `main` to parse the arguments from CLI, and *then* it calls some other function `do_stuff(...)` and it's passing in the *parsed* arguments.  In your case, you would call `do_stuff` directly since you presumably don't need to parse username/password from CLI but instead are reading them from a file or whatever.

Comment: Ah I see. So I'm now thinking I need to refactor all the following code where `args.i`, 'args.u`, and `args.p` etc. are called, by assigning them proper variable names which will be arguments to my `do_stuff()` function, like `def do_stuff(var_i=None, var_u=None, var_p=None, ...)`. Although, there are like 15-20 variables here; is there an easier way to do that? This would require me doing `var_i = args.i; var_p = args.p; ...` inside `main()` in order to call it within that function. Is that just the price of admission here?

Comment: Yes. Once the arguments are parsed, you shouldn't really be passing around the argparse namespace object itself.  It's just a simple container for the convenience of having one object returned by parser.parse_args().

Comment: That makes sense to me I am curious, however, why the `parse_args()` method returns a `Namespace` object. What is the advantage of this over a simple `dict`?

Comment: Good question, one that I have often wondered myself. Often the first thing I'll do with it is convert it to a dict with `d = vars(args)`  ;)    I think the `argparse.py` author may have just preferred the javascript style object/attribute syntax to use for a simple/flat bag of names and values.

Comment: That's interesting; I suppose that makes sense. So I have tried to refactor the code so that I now have `if __name__ == "__main__":` calling `main()`, which then calls some type of `do_stuff()` method. It still seems to function fine when called from a command line, but I can't get `do_stuff` to function on its own when called. I'm wondering if there is some syntax in the function that only applies to command line applications. To see exactly what I'm working with, the function is listed here: https://github.com/Linekio/getmyancestors/blob/master/getmyancestors.py (see line 886)